# Detect Fragment in ViewPager inside a Fragment of another ViewPager visible

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, setuservisiblehint

For example, I have

```
MainActivity (contain a ViewPager)
  Fragment0
  Fragment1 (contain a ViewPager)
          Fragment1a
          Fragment1b
  Fragment2
```

I want to refresh `Fragment1a` every time it visible so I use `setUserVisibleHint` inside `Fragment1a` but not working well.

When I switch between fragment `Fragment1a` and `Fragment1b`, `setUserVisibleHint` of `Fragment1a` **called**
However when I go from fragment `Fragment0` to `Fragment1` or `Fragment2` to `Fragment1` `setUserVisibleHint` of `Fragment1a (and Fragment1b)` **not called**

How can I detect `Fragment1a (and Fragment1b)` visible? Any help or suggestion would be great appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

setUserVisibleHint also not working me I used another way to update data in fragment when view pager change fragment, Below is The way,

```
 viewpager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    try {
                        if(viewPagerAdapter.getItem(position) instanceof Fragment1a){
                            Fragment1a frag1 = (Fragment1a) viewPagerAdapter.getItem(position);
                            frag1.updateData(data); // here is the public method of fragment which declared for udpate data in fragment
                        }else if(viewPagerAdapter.getItem(position) instanceof Fragment1b){
                            Fragment1b frag2 = (Fragment1b) viewPagerAdapter.getItem(position);
                            frag2.updateData(data); // here is the public method of fragment which declared for udpate data in fragment
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                }
            });
viewpager.setCurrentItem(0);
```

This way you can update data directly Just you need to create one public method in your fragment.

Here is the Adapter

```
class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
        private final List<TabModel> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
            super(manager);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return mFragmentList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return mFragmentList.size();
        }

        public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, TabModel title) {
            mFragmentList.add(fragment);
            mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            return mFragmentTitleList.get(position).getTabName();
        }

    }
```

Comment: inside `getItem()` of `ViewPager` adapter, I always create new `Fragment`. Example, `public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            if (position == 0) {
                return new Fragment1a();
            }
            return new Fragment1b();
        }`. Therefore, anytime I call getItem, new fragment will create

Comment: Okay, Then its may be causing problem  you need to define array for that.

Comment: I found a problem, `onPageSelected` not call when I go from `Fragment0` to `Fragment1`

Comment: Are you using PageIndicator for ViewPager?

Comment: After registering listener you need to call first time viewpager.setCurrentItem(0);